# ERROR: Invalid query, ERROR: Call cancelled

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

There is an error in my program when i execute this command:
`auto cmdout = _popen("tasklist", "r");`
The output is:

```
ERROR: Invalid query
ERROR: Call cancelled
```

What is wrong? I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and a standard c++ program.

I've tried to change `auto cmdout` to `FILE* cmdout`.

Comment: [`_popen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen) is not part of the Windows API. Including the *Windows.h* header is neither required nor related.

Comment: I know but i'm using it in my program for other functions.

Comment: We don't care about your program. We care about your issue. A [mcve] is the most efficient way to present your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that i used "r" as the second argument instead of "w".